# How can I see a list of status-completed questions sorted by when they were completed?

Tags: feature-request, questions, sorting, moderator-tags

I'd like to see a list of "status-completed" questions so I can tell what has changed lately. Right now you can see everything with that tag, and you can sort by date. However, this is the date the question was asked, not when the suggestion was implemented. Is there any way to see sort this way? Is this something that could be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to [sort by active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=status-completed&sort=active&pagesize=15). While this will introduce some false positives (i.e. recent activity other than the addition of `status-completed`), you will be able to see what posts have been recently marked as well. Protip: If Jeff Atwood is the last modifier, there's a good chance that modification is the addition of the tag.

Comment: Well, it would have worked.  But now that we have this question and you posted how to do it, everyone will be reading through those items today and making changes that throw the order off ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, but you could try and rank them by the number of votes they receive. Atwood said in the past that they tend to take on the ones with the highest vote totals first, so that may be an indicator of the order of completion.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the RSS feed of the tag?